# Postfix won't start at boot

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, boot

I have a server with ubuntu 10.04 and i've installed postfix.
It works but when the server is restarted it doesn't start automatically.

I've tried with:

```
 update-rc.d postfix defaults
```

But doesn't works neither it.

How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: What do you your logs say?  Boot messages?  Init system symlinks?  *Any* useful diagnostic information whatsoever?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't start or fails to start ? The distinction is critical.

Start it by hand using `postfix start` and see what is logged.

Comment: manually start well but i need to start it automatically on boot

Comment: Check your init script invocations, then. On Ubuntu, this has migrated to using `upstart` instead of sysvinit, so you may need to look in both places.